# How to do take webcam picture with repeatitively with a given interval (ffmpeg)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, camera

The command

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -vframes 3 /tmp/vid-$ts.%01d.jpg
```

allows to take 3 frames with a certain interval.

How do I specify the time interval between each shot.

---

PS:

I am interested in finding the time interval from which the LED webcam is being triggered. The previous command is activating my webcam LED.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ... the minimum you can get is 1 frame per second.

Depending of version, to keep it saving to same file, you should use `-updatelast 1` or `-update 1` switch.

For delayed frame capture, I would suggest using `fswebcam`, it has `-D` (delay) switch.